# Is it normal if ceramic pan looks like that after the first use?

Tags: pan, ceramic

Is it ok that it looks like that after I roasted with no oil (first use)? I tried to rub it off really good it with a soft tissue and a dish soap. Except whatever left on the surface (what you see on the photo) food wasn't sticking to it.
[image]

Comment: does the surface feels greasy when you rub it when its dried? if it does clean a little few more times, cuz i think thats grease...

Comment: Do you feel any residue on the surface of the pan? If so, you probably need to clean it more. If not, it is probably discoloration that will remain, but is harmless.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe so... it looks more like cooking residue to me. But you should be able to clean it sufficiently with one of the tricks below.

One trick, which I've used for any type of pan, is to put a small amount of water in it, then heat the water to the boiling point and let it cool. It softens up anything left on the surface, making cleaning much easier.

Another thing I do on a regular basis is using one of two products: Barkeeper's Friend, or Bon Ami. Similar to baking soda *[mentioned on the WikiHow page: [How to Clean Ceramic Pans](https://www.wikihow.com/Clean-Ceramic-Pans)]*. All three are gentle, slightly abrasive cleansers that should not damage your pan surfaces.

Comment: The question was not "How do I clean my pan?".